# Even without internet connection how to post the data and images into server

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Hi i'm working with http POST data and images, it works well when the wifi/ internet connection is available. But when switch off the mobile data / wifi it shows the some issue as follows:

```
error=Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://moneymonkey.tokiiyo.com/api/policy, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://moneymonkey.tokiiyo.com/api/policy, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSUnderlyingError=0x16ef25f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8}}})
```

I use the code for HTTP post method are as follows:

```
func barButtonItemClicked(barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem)
{


    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://moneymonkey.tokiiyo.com/api/policy");

    let typeItem: InsuranceType = InsuranceManager.sharedInstance.TypeArray[0]
    //let typeItem = InsuranceManager.sharedInstance
    let compItem = InsuranceManager.sharedInstance

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let param = [
        "api_key"  : "AiK58j67",
        "api_secret"    : "a#9rJkmbOea90-",
        "phone"    : "\(mobile)",
        "policy_type"   :   "\(typeItem.name)",
        "company"   :   "\(compItem.selectedCompany.cname)"
    ]

    print("Policy_type: \(typeItem.name)")
    print("Company: \(compItem.selectedCompany.cname)")
    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")



    let imageData = uploadImage?.highestQualityJPEGNSData

    if(imageData==nil)  { return; }

    request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file[]", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("******* response = \(response)")

        // Print out reponse body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")
        do{

            _ = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            });
        }
        catch
        {

            // report error
          print("Oops!! Something went wrong\(error)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Message", message:"Your document was uploaded successfully to our Server.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "DONE", style: .Default) { _ in
        // Put here any code that you would like to execute when
        // the user taps that OK button (may be empty in your case if that's just
        // an informative alert)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("listSegue", sender: self)
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}

}

func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString1("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString1("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString1("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    let filename = "upload.png"

    let mimetype = "image/jpeg"

    body.appendString1("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString1("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString1("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(imageDataKey)
    body.appendString1("\r\n")



    body.appendString1("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}

func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
}

extension NSMutableData {

func appendString1(string: String) {
    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    appendData(data!)
}
}
```

Can any one please guide me, how to upload even without internet connection. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't. How can you upload even without a network connection?

Answer (score 5):

Its not possible to upload data if internet connection is not available.

But you can store that data into Local DB if internet is not available, and you can post that data whenever internet connection will be appear. and also remove from local db when data has been uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

**Its not possible** to upload data to server  internet connection is not available on device. but you can keep the data in locally, at the same time check the **reachability** in always or some time interval, when it reaches send the data from local database to server and delete the item from locally (if you need)